# Including an editing button in a Datatable

Tags: php, ajax, datatable, datatables

I've been trying to do this for several days, but hope someone could just have a better idea than me, I'm trying include an edit button to my Datatable but since I'm calling the data using the method in my Controller, I am not able to find a way to make this button work

Here is my Datatable method:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/css/scroller.jqueryui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="/js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
<script src="https:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/2.0.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<style type="text/css">

    .loader {
        position:fixed;
        opacity: 0.5;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: url('/images/double_ring.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249, 249, 249, 249);
    }

    .table tr:hover { background-color: #eeeeee;}

    .content { background-color:white; }

</style>


<div id="loader" class="loader" style="display:none;"></div>

<h3 id='dashboard_title_header'>Pending Proposals</h3>

<br/>
</br>

<table id="table_roster" class="display nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Proposal Number</th>
            <th>Proposal Type</th>
            <th>Sponsor Code</th>
            <th>Prime Sponsor Code</th>
            <th>Sponsor Assigned Proposal Number</th>
            <th>Department Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Submission Deadline Date</th>
            <th>Project Start Date</th>
            <th>Proposal Specialist</th>
            <th>PI</th>
        </tr>  
    </thead>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

function format ( d ) {

    return '<table id="table_child" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>IRG:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[11]+'</td>'+
            '<td>IRG Date:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[12]+'</td>'+
            '<td>Council Cycle:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[13]+'</td>'+
            '<td>Score:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[14]+'</td>'+
            '<td>Percentile:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[15]+'</td>'+
            '<td>Assessment:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d[16]+'</td>'+
            '<td>'+
            '<button class="edit-model btn btn-info">'+
            '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>'+ 
            'Edit'+
            '</button>'+
            '</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#table_roster').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        ajax:           "/getproposals",
        //paging: true,
        //pageLenght: '10',
        deferRender:    true,
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollY:        400,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        scroller:       true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        "columnDefs": [
                {
                    className: "dt-body-center",
                    targets: -1,
                    defaultContent: ["<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit text-info editButton' aria-hidden='true'></i>"]
                    
                }
            ]
    });

    $('#table_roster tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var datas = table.row( this ).data();

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
        
       //EditProposal(data[0]);

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.edit-model', function() {
        $('#footer_action_button').text(" Update");
        $('#footer_action_button').addClass('glyphicon-check');
        $('#footer_action_button').removeClass('glyphicon-trash');
        $('.actionBtn').addClass('btn-success');
        $('.actionBtn').removeClass('btn-danger');
        $('.actionBtn').removeClass('delete');
        $('.actionBtn').addClass('edit');
        $('.modal-title').text('Edit');
        $('.deleteContent').hide();
        $('.form-horizontal').show();
        var stuff = $(this).data('info').split(',');
        fillmodalData(stuff)
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });

});

function EditProposal(id) {
    window.open("/proposals/" + id);
}


</script>
```

And this is my method in the Controller

```
   public function getProposals()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT proposal_number, proposal_type, sponsor_code, prime_sponsor_code, sponsor_assigned_proposal_number, award_admin_dept_code, status, submission_deadline_date, project_start_date, proposal_specialist, lname, IRG, IRGDate, CouncilCycleNumber, ScoreNumber, PercentageNumber, AssessmentEntry FROM proposal LEFT JOIN pendingproposals USING(proposal_id)  LEFT JOIN proposal_research_team USING(proposal_id) WHERE proposal.status in ('Unsubmitted','Dept Approval In Process', 'Admin Office In Process', 'JIT Request Received', 'JIT Submitted', 'Submitted to Sponsor', 'Sub 1/4: Awaiting Agreement', 'Sub 2/4: Under Negotiation', 'Sub 3/4: Partially Executed') AND role = 'Lead Principal Investigator';";
        $results = \DB::connection('mysql2')->select( \DB::raw($sql) );

        $data = array();
        $i = 0;

        foreach ($results as $r) {

            $data[$i] = array($r->proposal_number, $r->proposal_type, $r->sponsor_code, $r->prime_sponsor_code, $r->sponsor_assigned_proposal_number, $r->award_admin_dept_code, $r->status, $r->submission_deadline_date, $r->project_start_date, $r->proposal_specialist, $r->lname, $r->IRG, $r->IRGDate, $r->CouncilCycleNumber, $r->ScoreNumber, $r->PercentageNumber, $r->AssessmentEntry);
            $i++;
        }

        $results2 = ["sEcho" => 1,
            "iTotalRecords" => count($data),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
            "aaData" => $data];

        return json_encode($results2);
    }
```

I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Is the Ajax request not getting any response from controller or are you getting some other error?

Comment: No, I'm getting everything but not the buttons, all my database data is shown on the table but the button isn't showing at all

Comment: Is the glyphicon library included? You need to post the page HTML here

Comment: Thank you all, it seems I forgot a <th> in the HTML table, thank you Chilarai, if you didn't say "post the entire HTML table" I wouldn't have noticedm I posted it for reference in case anyone faces that :)